# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID..Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
protected void btnRecycle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();
    System.Collections.IEnumerator ie = mgr.ApplicationPools.GetEnumerator();

    while (ie.MoveNext())
    {
                    ddlApplicationPool.Items.Add(((Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool)(ie.Current)).Name);
    }

}
```

**Error:**

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).**

Comment: I get the same problem. Would love to know the answer!

Comment: Please provide more background or an answer if you ever found one.

Comment: I resolved this issue by realizing that IIS wasn't installed and installing IIS on the boxes where this code was executing. I'm assuming your situation is more complex than this, but just in case, i posted this anyway.

Answer (score 7):

This exception gets thrown if IIS is not installed in Windows.  You can use that exception as a dependency checker.

To install IIS, do the following:

Windows Start Menu > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off > check the top node in the "Internet Information Services" tree

[image]

EDIT:

A better way is just to check for the service this way.

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("World Wide Web Publishing Service");
```