# Azure Emulator stuck

Tags: azure, emulation, azure-worker-roles, azure-compute-emulator, azure-emulator

I'm working on azure WorkerRole project in `VS2015`, `SDK 2.9`. The role works good in cloud, but when i'm trying to run it locally with FullEmulator, role can't be started:

> [fabric] Role Instance: 
>   deployment29(116).MyComp.Engine.Deploy.MyProject.Engine.Azure.0
>
> [fabric] Role state Unknown
>
> [fabric] Role state Busy
>
> [fabric] Role state Unknown
>
> [fabric] Role state Busy
>
> [fabric] Role state Unknown
>
> [fabric] Role state Busy
>
> [fabric] Role state Destroyed
>
> [fabric] Role state Busy

[image]

looks like role is restarting endlesly, the interesting thing is, that break point at the begining of the `OnStart()` doesn't hit

How to detect the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found only one way to detect the reason - to look into event logs. There were a lot of errors from emulator. I suugest to check these categories:

- `Windows Logs\Application event log`
- `Applications and Services Logs\Windows Azure event log`
- `Windows Logs\System event log`

  I have found the reason - the role was  misconfigured.

  [this article](http://mhuensch.azurewebsites.net/azure-storage-wont-start/) can be useful

Comment: Which category you found the entries under? I have none in Applications and Services Logs/Windows Azure.

Comment: @Piedone sorry, i don't remember . Look to errors (my guess windows logs-> applications contains such errors), may be you will find errors from azure emulator.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately nothing there iether.

Comment: @Piedone looks strange, log records should be there, i added some categories into my answer. But in general you can create you filter (pull all events into one category and filter them)

Comment: I mean nothing from the Emulator is there, I see plenty of entries from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through my event logs I noticed the following error,

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered

After googling for that I found [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172439/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-error) that told me I had to install IIS. I had recently gotten a new computer and this doesn't seem to be part of the basic Windows install. After installing IIS it started right up.